# Open modal windows after submiting PHP contact form (AJAX? jQuery?)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, contacts

I have *reformulated my first question* because it was too vague I believe!

**The case: santz.net/index.contacto.html** (if you want to try sending something it's okay... I recieve it so no problem)

Here's my code for.....

**The Contact Form:**

```
    <form id="contact-form" name="contact-form" class="p25" action="contact.php" method="post">
        <fieldset>
            <label class="name">
                <input class="input" type="text" value="Nombre" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Nombre'){this.value = '';}" onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value='Nombre';}" name="php_name" />
            </label>
            <label class="email">
                <input class="input" type="email" value="Email" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Email'){this.value = '';}" onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value='Email';}" name="php_email" />
            </label>
            <label class="phone">
                <input class="input" type="tel" value="Teléfono" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Teléfono'){this.value = '';}" onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value='Teléfono';}" name="php_phone" />
            </label>
            <label class="message">
                <textarea class="textarea" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Mensaje'){this.value = '';}" onblur="if(this.value == ''){this.value='Mensaje';}" name="php_message">Mensaje</textarea>
            </label>

            <div class="buttons-wrapper ml20">
                <div class="submit-comment">
                    <span></span>
                    <input type="reset" value="Cancelar">
                </div>
                <div class="submit-comment ml25">
                    <span></span>
                    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
                    <div id="clicker"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

**And here's my PHP code:**

```
<?php
$field_name = $_POST['php_name'];
$field_email = $_POST['php_email'];
$field_phone = $_POST['php_phone'];
$field_message = $_POST['php_message'];

$field_sender = 's2@hotmail.com';

$mail_to = 's@hotmail.com';
$subject = 'Mensaje via Santz.net de '.$field_name;

$body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Phone: '.$field_phone."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;

$headers = 'From: '.$field_sender."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Gracias por contactarse, en breve, me pondre en contacto.\n\nSantz Design | www.santz.net');
        window.location = 'index.contacto.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('El envio fallo. Por favor, envie un mail directamente a info@santz.net');
        window.location = 'index.contacto.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

**What I want do do is the following...**

The contact form right now works, and I get the email... that's fine... so:

1- I need to eliminate the page refresh/redirection when you submit the form
2- To replace the refresh/reload/redirect, I need that when the form is submited, I want it to open a modal window (I would put any content there...) *(example: **pixeden.com/media-icons/soft-media-icons-set-vol-2** ...the dialog that opens when I hit "Download")*

This is what another user recommended me for the modal box (it's quite nice): **mywebdeveloperblog.com/my-jquery-plugins/modalpoplite**

The thing is I don't understand how to delete the reload/refresh/redirect issue after submiting and I don't understand how to connect the modal box opening event after the form is submited...

**NOTE:**

I'm quite new to all of this (I'm only aged 17), so I'm not a programmer... just a designer that understands little programming... but I'm learning to program web so I need help.

**If PHP is not the way to go and I need to chenge of programming technology, please let me know. I'm open to any programming language that fully solves my problem!**

Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this script in the `<head>` of your contact form:

```
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#dialog-modal").dialog({
        height: 140,
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false
    });
    $('#contact-form').submit(function() {
        $("#dialog-modal").dialog("open");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function() {
                $("#dialog-modal").dialog("close");
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Paste this anywhere in the body:

```
<div id="dialog-modal">Form submitted</div>
```

Comment: Samuel, this is great! It does exactly what I wanted. Now I must only customize and style everything and that's kind of the only thing I understand quite a lot about! So thanks indeed! However, I had a problem... Check the page: http://santz.net/index.contacto.html, you'll notice that at the bottom, if you didn't yet submit any form, the "dialog-modal" div isn't hidden, I mean, the text is right there (check at the bottom left). And the second thing is that I submitted the form but this doesn't clear out after ir!, would you please help me with this two issuess? Thanks a lot! Sory to bother!

Comment: I'm Santiago B. I sent you a message to your Facebook! If you can and I'm not bothering you please answer me! Thanks a lot! EDIT: I have set display:none but the dialog's content is also "none" when it should show up!

Comment: Cool. You're great. Last issue I believe... Try it yourself... please. Visit the page and check!! When you fill the form and hit submit, the form is succesfully submited BUT the dialog doesn't open. The dialog only opens if you click submit again once you have already submited. (It's like if it need a double click... very rare...)

Comment: didn't correct the problem... it seems what I'm asking is quite tricky!!

Comment: It didn't... the dialog opens but the form doesn't submit. very strange taking into account that the success triggers the "open" event.

Comment: Would you like me to create a new thread but with the full code in it? So that if you want you can take a deeper look. I'm trying to understand what you are telling me to do. I starting to believe this is the best way to learn... (OH! I'm affraid that mabye those methods aren't working because I'm not using the jQuery UI modal box. I'm using another one... the one I provided on the link! Can that be the issue? Again, do you need the code of the modal box I'm using? It has a particular .js file... that I'm once again trying to understand!) Jest tell me. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm again on the double clic... because I restred the previows "working but faulty" version ahah. Take a look. I finished styling the modal box content: http://santz.net/index.contacto.html

Comment: Thanks a lot! I close this because we achieved 90% of everything! We just need to find out what the bug is.... Thanks indeed! Continued here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15237989/final-ajax-jquery-php-form-submission-and-modal-box-open-on-success

Answer (score 1):

Santz, they are most likely using ajax and jquery UI dialog boxes to display when the javascripts ajax response comes back. Here is a nice little tutorial explaining how they accomplish this. Good Luck.

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/

Comment: Thanks I read it very usefull to understand what Samuel is doing! Thanks indeed!