# Final: AJAX/jQuery/PHP Form submission and modal box open on success

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

Thanks to Samuel Liew and other great helpers, the issue has been fixed.

As putting everything here was a mess, and it was poorly explained in the overall solution, I dediced to make a explanatory in my own web site.

I leave the DEMO for you to see if that's what you're looking for, and I leave the TUTORIAL for you to learn how to do this.

TUTORIAL: http://santz.com.ar/blog/ajax-form-submit-open-modal-box/

DEMO: http://santz.com.ar/files/demos/ajax-form-submit-open-modal-box/

Hope I helped you! Thanks to all the ones that helped me!

---

@Samuel Liew, and other great helpers. THE ISSUE HAS BEEN FIXED. I'll leave corected code for future guys that need this.

**The case:** http://santz.net/index.contacto.html (no longer available)

THIS WAS THE PROBLEM:

> **Target:** The "website" must open a dialog/modal box/modal window after successful form submission.
>
> **Issue:** The form submits successfully but the dialog/modal box/modal window doesn't open (rarely, it does open if you make
>   another click...)
>
> [Try it, that's why I gave you the link. There's no problem, the site
>   is mine and I recieve the messages]
>
> **I hope you can help me... the idea is quite simple! When the user submits the form, a dialog popsup instantly!**

THANKS A LOT!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, move the dialog function outside of the submit function:

```
$(function() {
    $('#popup-wrapper').modalPopLite({
        openButton: '#clicker',
        closeButton: '#close-btn'
    });
    $('#contact-form').submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function() {
                $('#contact-form')[0].reset();
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Samuel, that didn't work because the Form isn't sent. I have an idea... though, I don't know if it's correct...

Comment: EXPLANATION (using that that you edited): we separated the clicker (that's the trigger to open the modal box). I think that if we can integrate both functions into one triggering action, it should work. I mean, if we tell the website that when I click the '#clicker' (the form's submit button) it should also submit the form, interpreting the triggering of the '#clicker' action as a dual task thing... (simpler: you hit the Submit ('#clicker') button and the web site runs both scripts: submits form and clears it and also opens the modal box. ALL this when the '#clicker' button is triggered)

Comment: Yes! That's the problem... the form isn't submited but the box '#clicker' event is triggered

Comment: Samuel I can't get around it... I don't know how to fix this

Comment: Samuel I need to chat with you. Please send me an email to santz@hotmail.com.ar

Comment: No I changed the whole plugin for a simpler one... Sory and thanks for everything. Please understand that you really built up the 90% of this. I just tried to do what you told me, so I really appreciate that. Thanks a lot Samuel!

Comment: @Santz - In that case, you could at least give this an upvote?

Comment: Wow sorry Samuel! Right I mised that. At least I owe you that! Thanks a lot again. Of course, I gave you credit for the awesome help!

Comment: Actually I edited the post! That's best. The other thing was a bit selfish!!! Kind regards