# Submitting a form when calling Bootstrap modal

Tags: php, forms, twitter-bootstrap, submit, modal-dialog

im new to bootstrap, and i want to do this:

when i press a button i want to submit the form, and then open a modal, how can i do this? so i get the post data on the modal. I've tried with two buttons, first one submit the form and the other one opens the modal, if i do it in that order it works fine, but i would like to do it in only one button.

any help?

this is my button:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" data-id="<?php echo $rol['rol_id'];?>" class="open btn btn-primary btn-lg">Launch demo modal</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bad method and you should be using AJAX for this instead. When the modal is clicked, an ajax request should fire. Wait for its response (and return the data you need). If its successful then load the modal with the returned data.

> I've tried with two buttons, first one submit the form and the other
>   one opens the modal, if i do it in that order it works fine, but i
>   would like to do it in only one button.

From this I assume that after the `POST` you display the returned data within the modal. If you want to follow this method you will need to write some Javascript within the HTML to fire the modal after a `POST` request.

```
<?php if ($_POST['submitted']) { ?>
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#myModal").modal();
});
<?php } ?>
```

I would recommend against this as you have to put this in a `.php` or `.phtml` file, AJAX would be better suited in this case.

Answer (score 0):

// This question has already been solved elsewhere... I suggest following this link and doing what @Samuel Liew recommends.  [AJAX/jQuery/PHP Form submission and modal box open on success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15237989/final-ajax-jquery-php-form-submission-and-modal-box-open-on-success)  @fruitp is correct AJAX is the way to go with this.