# Boostrap 3 - How to display modal form dialog box when after an ajax submission

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a boostrap panel which is turned into a modal. I have a form on the same page which is contains a modal which looks more like a panel based on the theme I am using

I do not know how to load the modal when the form returns a successful submission
I have seen various similar questions such as this one

[Final: AJAX/jQuery/PHP Form submission and modal box open on success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15237989/final-ajax-jquery-php-form-submission-and-modal-box-open-on-success)

This is a button click that opens the modal but i dont know how to do it on ajax success

Small Modal

```
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="modal" class="close" type="button">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Small Modal</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">...</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The button is obviously toggling the modal on/off but how do i control the modal through jquery

Many thanks for your help

Comment: have you tried anything? look here [Bootstrap modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" id="modalExample" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="modal" class="close" type="button">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Small Modal</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">...</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

call it as : `$('#modalExample').modal();`

Answer (score 0):

You can find a lot of info in [Google](http://www.google.com) and on [GetBootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals).
Here is a short example:

**HTML**

```
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" id="modalToDisplay" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button aria-hidden="true" data-dismiss="modal" class="close" type="button">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Small Modal</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">...</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function doAjaxCall() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "", //url to your page
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(datas) {

            $('#modalToDisplay').modal('show');

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi. I do understand people's frustration with the question but if I understood what i was doing i woudlnt be asking in the first place :) I dont know ajax or jquery or bootstrap so I'm trying my best to not ask rubbish questions :)  Thanks for your help

Comment: There are no rubbish questions but if you search the internet you can find a lot of documentations and examples that will help you understanding the frameworks. Try it out with the answer I gave you.